# anchor tag href not working for anchor having DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I have two anchor tags:

1)For logging out user

```
  <a href="{$Site.HostPath}/portal/<%=companyid %>/logout" style="color: #888; text-decoration: none">&nbsp;|&nbsp;Logout</a></li>
```

whose href is working correctly.

2) For showing and updating user profile.

```
 User: <a class="something" href="{$Site.HostPath}/portal/<%=companyid %>/profile" style="text-decoration: none"><span class="sales-user-info" style="" ><%= username%></span></a>
```

whose href is not getting triggered.

What is the problem??

Comment: Can you show the generated html?

Comment: href is replaced by valid url. for ex `http://local.goal.crew/portal/175/profile`

Comment: That's not the generated html, that's the url

Comment: Do you have any event listeners attached to the user profile anchor tag? One of those might be calling `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: what i am trying to say is only href url,company id and username are replaced by new values. there is nothing change in DOM

Comment: Without more information one can't say more about it

Comment: need more html/css markup to see what is going on. saying that "nothing change in DOM" means nothing without it.

Comment: Can you share the generated HTML of 2nd script?